# I don't know what this symbol means

Tags: group-theory, physics, spherical-harmonics

I somehow made it to grad school without coming across this symbol:

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\
m_1 & m_2 & m_3
\end{array}\right) $

Here, $l_i$ and $m_i$ are all integers, and I think maybe the value of this expression is either 0 or 1 depending on the values.

What's the name of this symbol, and what is its value?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner6j-Symbol.html ?

Answer (score 4):

Since spherical harmonics was mentioned then this is most likely the [Wigner $3j$ symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner3j-Symbol.html).

This symbol is useful if you want to descibe the product of two spherical harmonics expanded in a series of spherical harmonics

$$Y^{m_1}_{l_1}Y^{m_2}_{l_2} = \sum_{l,m}\sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)(2l+1)}{4\pi}}\begin{pmatrix}
  l_1 & l_2 & l \\[8pt]
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  l_1 & l_2 & l\\
  m_1 & m_2 & m
\end{pmatrix}\overline{Y}_{m}^l$$

and it also appears in integral formulas of spherical harmonics like [for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol#Relation_to_spherical_harmonics):

$$\int Y_{l_1m_1}(\theta,\varphi)Y_{l_2m_2}(\theta,\varphi)Y_{l_3m_3}(\theta,\varphi)\,\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\varphi = \sqrt{\frac{(2l_1+1)(2l_2+1)(2l_3+1)}{4\pi}}
\begin{pmatrix}
  l_1 & l_2 & l_3 \\[8pt]
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  l_1 & l_2 & l_3\\
  m_1 & m_2 & m_3
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

This notation is often used to write a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Notation) $\sigma$ so that $l_i \mapsto m_i$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is indeed a common use of this symbol, but unfortunately it is not the way the symbol being used here. The $l$ and $m$ here refer to the $l$ and $m$ that appear in spherical harmonics $Y_l^m$. I don't have much more information than that.

Answer (score 0):

This usually represents the function $f$ with domain $\{l_1,l_2,l_3\}$, such that $f(l_1)=m_1$, $f(l_2)=m_2$, and $f(l_3)=m_3$.

($l$ is a horrible name for a variable. It looks like a $1$ when you draw it. $\ell$ is better.)